# When i am removing a data from firebase using react js it deletes the data and one null value is entered. How can I avoid null entry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

While deleting the data from firebase database null value is getting inserted into firebase.

```
deleteImag = e => {
    const val = e.target.value;    
    var x = '';
    const rootRef = fire.database().ref();
    const fooRef = rootRef.child(`assets/${this.state.id}`);
    fooRef.on("value", snap => {
      const foo = snap.val();
      if (foo !== null) {
        Object.keys(foo).forEach(key => {
          if (foo[key].id = val) {
            console.log(key);
            x = key;
            // The Object is foo[key]
            var res = null;
            console.log(foo[key].id);
            fire.database().ref(`assets/${this.state.id}/${x}`).remove();          
       }
        });
      }
    });  
};
```

JSON:

```
{
  "hero" : {
    "img" : "http://aws-website-testing-slv0n.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/CornHole3.jpg"
  },
  "id" : "urn:microsense:cms:asset:80c71fdb-0d32-41de-8170-8e35409b8e63",
  "purpose" : "activity",
  "thumbnail" : {
    "img" : "http://aws-website-testing-slv0n.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/CornHole3.jpg"
  }
}, null, null, {
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhXg8.jpg)

Comment: I don't see any `null` value in your database. Can you point out what specific value is being written when you call `remove()`?

Comment: When I call remove()  null is getting inserted at the removed node place. It's not reflected here once I export the data in json from Firebase there I find it.

Comment: In that case please replace the screenshot with the actual JSON that shows the problematic value that you're asking about.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sir i have attached the json image please help me out.

Comment: My initial feeling is that these elements are in an array, in which case you're seeing [Firebase's handling of arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). Can you replace the screenshot with the actual JSON as text, and make sure the containing element is also in there? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Hi  sir i have attached the log in image link.how many times i delete it creates like empty*12  means 12 item i have deleted.

Comment: Hmm.... I'm not sure what's going on there. It's hard to follow from the code and data. I still have a feeling you have an array of assets with sequential numeric indexes, in which case the link I gave about arrays likely explains what you're seeing.

Comment: I did notice `if (foo[key].id = val)` in your code just now, which is an assignment, not a comparison. It should probably be `if (foo[key].id == val)`.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen Sir  it was array issue on it. The article helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was array issue. When we remove an array in Firebase it replace that element with null. So the above article was helpful for me. Thanks